# When to add impedances to network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, multimodal-network

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 for desktop and will be using point and click to digitise a cycle network shapefile and network data sets then use model builder or python. 
My aim is to assess the accessibility of my city by bicycle. To show impedances such as distance and slope, identify barriers such as intersections, and gaps in connectivity.

I am hoping to create a multi-modal network data set including an off road cycle path network, on road cycle path network and complete road network. I was wondering:

A - if it's best to keep these separate particularly the off road and on road cycle paths or merge them before building the network dataset?

B - whether to add surface information such as slope to these layers before building the network dataset?

C - how to produce a map with a bicycle level of service for each segment of the network, giving a classification e.g network segment that is flat, has an off-road cycle path would be identified as "Excellent"?

Would this best be done in ModelBuilder or python using the select tool?

Aim to visualise a bicycle suitability map and eventually an accessibility and bicycle friendliness.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format. As it stands I think your question is too broad because it is effectively asking potential answerers to identify any possible issues in any of six steps. I recommend that you perform a proof of concept on your workflow and if you identify an issue that is something that could be asked about here as focussed Q&A. I hope you will appreciate that if we were to provide reviews of workflow requests then we would probably be inundated by them, and all would be very time consuming for our volunteers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. its probably best to have both types in the same feature class but what attributes denoting which type of road/path it is

B. yes I would add the cost/slope to a attribute field in the road feature class.  You can use this for building your impedance\cost later on.

C. I do not quite understand the last question.  Are you wanting to exclude the unacceptable roads (ie roads that exceed your slope criteria)? If so I would use a definition query to exclude them before you build your network dataset.  That way they can not be traversed in the network.

Comment: thank you. I will join the data sets into the one feature class then add the cost/slope information.